# jboss drools - comparing derived strings

Tags: java, string, jboss, drools, rule-engine

**Working Rule:**

```
rule "it is morning before lunch"
    ruleflow-group "define_period"
    when
        $process: WorkflowProcessInstance()
        Hour(value >=6 && < 12) from $process.getVariable("hourOfDay")
    then 
        System.out.println("Its morning");
end
```

**Class Hour:**

```
public class Hour {
    private Integer value;
    public Hour() {}
    public Hour(Integer value) {
        this.value=value;
    }
    public void setValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value+"h";
    }
}
```

$process also contians another variable - 'period' which is of type 'String'. I want to use this instead of comparing the hour. How do I go about it. I have tried replacing:

`Hour(value >=6 && < 12) from $process.getVariable("hourOfDay")`

with

`String(this == "morning") from $process.getVariable("period")`

and

`String(value == "morning") from $process.getVariable("period")`

But that does not work.

Let me know if you need more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$process: WorkflowProcessInstance( period == 'morning')
```

instead of

```
 $process: WorkflowProcessInstance()
```